# How can I get the signature of an X509Certificate2 object using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, x509, x509certificate2

I need to get the signature and the algorithm used to create that signature out of a certificate with C#.

Can I do that? If yes, how?

Comment: Certificates have thumbprint, but no signature, if you carefully read MSDN documentation, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @lex-li Certificates have signature. .Net does not let you access it. Certificates do not have thumbprint. Thumbprint is Microsoft's invention, it is calculated by hashing the certificate content with SHA1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am developing now application with similar functionality. And I'm really dissapointed why Microsoft didn't add property Signature to X509Certificate2 class

I know how to do that via bouncycastle

Take it from there http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

Then add code

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using bcrypto = Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
```

.

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2("c:\\temp\\0c50000343119659.cer");
var certParser = new bcrypto.X509CertificateParser();
var privateCertBouncy = certParser.ReadCertificate(cert.GetRawCertData());
var xx = privateCertBouncy.GetSignature();
Array.Reverse(xx);
//Signature
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(xx));
//algorithm
Console.WriteLine(privateCertBouncy.SigAlgName);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I updated the code. It's strange but I get byte array in wrong order and I have to Reverse it.

Comment: Yeah I came across that and find it in a forum and fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to resort to Bouncy Castle,

https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/x509/X509Certificate.cs#L240

Its X509Certificate class gives you access to this property.

Comment: Thank you. Bouncy Castle is great !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AsnDecoder` along with information on the X509 v3 structure found in RFC3280 Section 4.1.
Compare the output of this function with `openssl x509 -noout -text -in <pem file>`

```
/// <summary>
/// RFC3280 Section 4.1
/// Depth 1 of the X509 v3 cert is
/// Certificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
///     tbsCertificate TBSCertificate,
///     signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
///     signatureValue BIT STRING
/// }
///
/// https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#section-4.1
/// </summary>
public static byte[] Signature(this X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    var signedData = certificate.RawDataMemory;
    AsnDecoder.ReadSequence(
        signedData.Span,
        AsnEncodingRules.BER,
        out var offset,
        out var length,
        out _
    );

    var certificateSpan = signedData.Span[offset..(offset + length)];
    AsnDecoder.ReadSequence(
        certificateSpan,
        AsnEncodingRules.BER,
        out var tbsOffset,
        out var tbsLength,
        out _
    );

    var offsetSpan = certificateSpan[(tbsOffset + tbsLength)..];
    AsnDecoder.ReadSequence(
        offsetSpan,
        AsnEncodingRules.BER,
        out var algOffset,
        out var algLength,
        out _
    );

    return AsnDecoder.ReadBitString(
        offsetSpan[(algOffset + algLength)..],
        AsnEncodingRules.BER,
        out _,
        out _
    );
}
```